How to add plain text (or comment) to DisplayFormula?
I would like to add a comment to (behind) a displayformula. Is there a (recommended) way to add 'plain text'/'a comment' to a displayformula?

Select Alt+0 and choose Display Formula, write the formula and text somewhere, select the text by mouse and go to /menu/format/fontfamily

